# Analyze lib usage within a packet

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a problem regarding the usage of libs in Eclipse. I want to know which lib is used in which package. 
I tried the search functionality but this did not really solve my issue.

I do not try to figure out which libs are used in general but which are used e.g. in the test package only.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to temporarily remove the library and see where you get errors.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea but I would have to test more than 100 libs... There must be a better way...